# Proper word for non-sequitur asides in TV and Film

Tags: single-word-requests, cinema

The TV show Family Guy very often, usually multiple times per episode, will cut away from the main plot to show a weird flashback or just a miniature story that is completely unrelated to the main plot even when it's framed as having been a flashback. Family Guy isn't the only show/movie that does things like this it just seems to be the one that does it the most often.

<s>Now, I don't know where I picked the term up from, but for the longest time, I've been referring to these asides as mise-en-scenes. But I'd just recently looked up a bunch of different definitions for that word, and it doesn't seem to quite fit.</s> (edit: it seems this section is confusing people. I'm not asking what mise-en-scene means, I'm asking what the word for the thing I've described in the first paragraph is)

But then, what *is* the proper term for these?

Comment: These are neither non-sequitur nor mis-en-scene. They might be danglers, subplots, stories within a story,  red herrings, metareferences... - it really depends on what is going on and whether it is really unrelated or possibly related in some subtle way etc.

Comment: @msam "These are neither non-sequitur" I'm specifically asking about the non-sequiturs. "nor mis-en-scene" Yeah, that's why I'm asking the question, because I realized I'd been using the wrong term.

Comment: [Mise-en-scène](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mise-en-sc%C3%A8ne) is way more general than you're using it. You're talking about one particular technique of storytelling, and mise en scene is about the whole mechanics of putting a story into a theater or film production.  It comes from the french meaning of 'director of a theater/film production'. I think what you are looking for is a word that encompasses flashbacks, asides, irrelevant vignettes, etc. Mise en scene is for the whole directorial enterprise, not for this one little story telling technique.

Comment: @Mitch Yeah, that's why I've asked the question... Sorry, was it confusing for me to mention my motivating reason for asking?

Comment: This may actually end up being irrelevant, but here's a [wiki list of terms used in movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_motion_picture_terms). More relevant would be a list of _story-telling_ techniques.

Comment: To think this out, what may happen is that the scriptwriter may have a lot of material for a story but not all of it is integral to whatever esthetic the author is trying to make. And some of these inconsistencies may not be edited out (in trying to be consistent or true) _or_ the one-off joke or scene may have enough of its own appeal to warrant being kept. Art isn't a car engine. That is some good stuff may not be on purpose. And there may not be a name for this technique even if it is purposeful. Sounds like a vaudeville thing, just throwing in extra jokes for fun.

Comment: @Mitch "vaudeville thing" Then might the right answer be "vignette"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sketch_comedy "An individual comedy sketch is a brief scene or vignette of the type formerly used in vaudeville"

Comment: 'vignette' is a small story within a much bigger story. 'vignetting' is a lighting technique to emphasize a center and deemphasize the surroundings. These are metaphorically related. I think 'cutaway' is exactly the word for the idea you're asking about, but 'vignette' might also work (but a vignette is probably more substantive than a cutaway that you're thinking of).

Comment: @Mitch The things in Family Guy very often are usually small but complete stories themselves. Perhaps they are "cutaway vignettes"? Since "cutaway" more refers to the editing technique rather than the type of content and "vignette" seems to speak more to the type of content.

Comment: just cutaway or just vignette would do. together seems pleonastic. but reading the wiki page, cutaway seems like probably what everyone else uses for just those instances you're referring to, Family Guy.

Answer (score 4):

You already gave the answer. The show itself, when it's being self-referential, calls these

> "cutaways".

The term is more general than that, though, according to [the article on it in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutaway_(filmmaking)):

> "... a **cutaway** scene is the interruption of a scene with the insertion of another scene, **generally unrelated or only peripherally related** to the original scene."

That article mentions *Family Guy* and its "cutaway gags".

Comment: Nice! Sometimes there's not a word for the thing you want. But it is so satisfying when there is.

Comment: They are *ironic* cutaways.